# PyQt5 - Translated texts do not appear in the GUI

Tags: python, internationalization, pyqt5

Despite existing, translated texts do not appear in my GUI.
Here is the main.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow
import sys, os

from view.MainWindow import MainWindow


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show(mainWindow)
    translator = QtCore.QTranslator()
    (filepath,filename)=os.path.split(__file__)
    trad_path=os.path.join(filepath,'translate','fr_FR.qm')
    print (trad_path)
    translator.load(trad_path)
    app.installTranslator(translator)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The main.py file is under a src folder alongside a  translate folder containing the fr_FR.qm file.

The print (trad_path)  shows that the path to the file is  correct

Inside , the MainWindow.py file I have  a showEvent() function that calls the set_translatable_textes() function

```
    def showEvent(self,ev):
        print('in show event')
        self.set_translatable_textes()

    def set_translatable_textes(self):
        self.choose_session_label.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate(
                'Main Window','A text that has translation'))
        #self.choose_session_label.setText('Untranslated text')

        self.edit_button.setText(self.tr('Edit'))
        #self.edit_button.setText('Untranslated text')
```

I try two kinds of translation :

1. With QCoreApplication.translate()
2. With tr()
   None of them is working. To be sure I call the function, I replace each statements with the commented statement under. They both work.

I am probably doing something wrong but what?

Answer (score 0):

How stupid!
The translator  was not ready at the time the MainWindow showed up.
I placed the translator stuff in main before MainWindow.show() and it became fine.